# How could the text written in editText modify the progressbar in Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm trying to make the progress bar interactive with the `editText`. When the number written in `editText` is greater than 10, the progress bar increases by 10%.

The code I wrote doesn't work of course but I don't see how to do it:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.first_gamble)

        val progressbar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
        val converter = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.gamblesum)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button6)


        button.setOnClickListener() {
            if (converter > '2') {
                with(progressbar) { incrementProgressBy(10) }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (converter.text.toString().toIntOrNull() is Int && converter.text.toString().toInt() > 10 {
    progressBar.progress = (progrrssBar.progress * 1.1).toInt()
}
```

You need to compare the value converted to an integer against an integer and not a string.
You can save the first conditional if the EditText only accepts numbers, otherwise you have to validate that I entered it

Answer (score 0):

I went with this approach:
In the view model create a private and public val. Public val is to be read from/ observed and private val to set the value. Public val gets its value from the private val.

In view model

```
    private val _progress: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }
val progress: LiveData<Int>
    get() = _progress
```

in the fragment / activity observe changes to progress. You can make the bar visible or not from here and set the value of the progress at the same time.

```
viewModel.progress.observe(this.viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Int> { progress ->
            var value = progress
            if (value>=1){binding.progressBar.isVisible
                binding.progressBar.progress = value
            }else{binding.progressBar.isVisible=false}
        })
```

Back in your view model you will need some way to reset the progress/make it invisible. For example:

```
  fun resetProgress() {
    _progress.value = 0
}
```

When you run some function or do something in the view model you can make the progress bar appear / disappear by changing the value of the private variable

```
fun getCurrentUserProfileData() = viewModelScope.launch {
    _progress.value = 1
    Log.i(TAG,"user profile : ${userProfile.value}")
    _progress.value = 50
    _userList.value= FirebaseProfileService.generateUserList()
    Log.i(TAG,"user profile List : ${userList.value}")
    _progress.value = 100
    resetProgress()
}
```